# Adding HTML inside PHP problems

Tags: php, html, css

Currently when using the below code, I get website that looks like this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hddTJ.png) (Had to paint out some info due to GDPR)

This is the code used:

```
<div class="page group">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    
    <div id="outer_wrapper">
      <div id="inner_wrapper">
        
        <?php
   $query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE ident ='".$currentName."' AND status ='Venter' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') DESC";
       if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
           $num_rows = 0;
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $num_rows++;
                  if ($num_rows > 0) {
                      echo '<div class="box">';
                      echo '<div class="Nwrapper">';
                      echo '<div id="NformContent">';
                      echo
                      "<tr><br>
                      <td><b>{$row['date']}</b></td><br>
                      <td> &nbsp; {$row['name']} </td> <b>/</b>
                      <td>{$row['gsm']} &nbsp; </td><br>
                      <td> &nbsp; {$row['email']} &nbsp; </td><br><br>
                      <td> &nbsp; <b>Info</b> &nbsp; <br> &nbsp; {$row['pp']} &nbsp; </td><br>
                      <td>Portering: {$row['transfer']}</td><br>
                      <td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};' class='aRS'>Oppdater status</a><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Ønsker du å angre salget?');\" href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};' class='aR'>Slett salg</a></td><br><br>
                      </tr>";
                      echo '</div>';
                      echo '</div>';
                      echo '</div>';
                  } else {
                      echo "No appointments";
                      break;
                  }
              }
              /*freeresultset*/
              $result->free();
          }
      ?>
      
      </div> <!-- inner_wrapper -->
      
      </div> <!-- outer_wrapper -->
      
      </div> <!-- col span_1_of_3 -->
      </div> <!-- section -->
      </div> <!-- page group -->
    
    <div class="lineWrapper"></div><br>
```

What I want to do is to hide the top horizontal boxes if the query return no value(0 number of rows(?)  num_rows). I have tried doing it like this, and put my whole code inside the PHP query:

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE ident ='".$currentName."' AND status ='Venter' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') DESC";
       if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
           $num_rows = 0;
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $num_rows++;
                  if ($num_rows > 0) {
                      ?>
                      
                      <div class="page group">
                      <div class="section">
                      <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                      <div id="outer_wrapper">
                      <div id="inner_wrapper">
                          
                          <?php
                      
                      echo '<div class="box">';
                      echo '<div class="Nwrapper">';
                      echo '<div id="NformContent">';
                      echo
                      "<tr><br>
                      <td><b>{$row['date']}</b></td><br>
                      <td> &nbsp; {$row['name']} </td> <b>/</b>
                      <td>{$row['gsm']} &nbsp; </td><br>
                      <td> &nbsp; {$row['email']} &nbsp; </td><br><br>
                      <td> &nbsp; <b>Info</b> &nbsp; <br> &nbsp; {$row['pp']} &nbsp; </td><br>
                      <td>Portering: {$row['transfer']}</td><br>
                      <td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};' class='aRS'>Oppdater status</a><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Ønsker du å angre salget?');\" href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};' class='aR'>Slett salg</a></td><br><br>
                      </tr>";
                      echo '</div>';
                      echo '</div>';
                      echo '</div>';
                      ?>
                      
                      </div> <!-- inner_wrapper -->
                      </div> <!-- outer_wrapper -->
                      </div> <!-- col span_1_of_3 -->
                      </div> <!-- section -->
                      </div> <!-- page group -->
                      
                      <div class="lineWrapper"></div><br>
                      
                      <?php
                  } else {
                      break;
                  }
              }
              /*freeresultset*/
              $result->free();
          }
      ?>
```

When I save, it all looks good, the top boxes are all gone, but now if the number of rows is higher then 0, and there are some value to show, it looks like this(each displays in a vertical order):
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jJYP.png)

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work like I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

There is while loop. Inside loop you open table row put chunk as $num_rows and close row, than goes another chunk in it's own row.
While loop works as loop - chunk after chunk - end of loop;
I'm not sure - you want them all horizontally? In one row?
Actually, you don't need any table for this, this isn't tabular content, more appropriate would be section or div or something similar.
Whatever you pick, for now it would be a 'box';

this is how it should go:
open a box,
query, fetch - if is empty do nothing {}
if isn't empty - write down chunk after chunk,
close box;
With no chunks it will be empty box - you can hide it with .css (or not...)

Other solution is to assign all chunks to variable $x.= chunk
and then - if (x) is not empty - open a box - write it (x) down - close box;
If the output (x) is big, may cause problem.

Next one solution - workaround :
$box = '<div>'; // echoing $box will open a box
query, fetch, if empty do nothing;
if not empty output - echo $box write first chunk, unset $box - following chunks won't echoing $box,
after loop, if $num_rows > 0 close box (if 0 rows there is no open box)